# Why is preoutgoing hook executed on Strip in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Could someone please explain why my `preoutgoing` hook gets executed on doing `hg strip` (Mercurial Strip)? Is there any chance to disable that behavior?

I'd expected the hook to run when doing `hg push`.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think hg internally does something like push when it runs strip because it does a backup first. Its like pushing to a file instead of to another repo, followed by what we think of as the real stripping action where the changesets are removed. This is very similar to how hg bundle works as well, to the best of my understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you see any chance to work around that behavior? Is it possible to determine the initial command (`hg push` vs. `hg strip`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the execution of my hook code, I've added the following lines of code to the very beginning of my hook:

```
if "%HG_SOURCE%" == "strip" (
    exit /b 0
)
```

Both `outgoing` and `preoutgoing` will be provided with a parameter indicating the source action. In Python, this parameter is called `source`, otherwise you can access the environment variable `HG_SOURCE`:

- `hg push` → `HG_SOURCE` is `push`
- `hg strip` → `HG_SOURCE` is `strip`

Based on that observation, you can simply evaluate the initial command.

Sources:

- [`preoutgoing`](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:preoutgoing)
- [Sources of changesets](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:sources)